# how to add commas to a integer string

Tags: python

I have a task to create a comma separated list. What I have now works except I'm trying to figure out how to remove the last comma. What I mean is it looks like this with my code 1,2,3, but I need to have it as 1,2,3 is there any way to change what I have now to do this.

```
new_string = new_string+str(numbers[index])+comma
```

Comment: That code doesn't even get to the comma part, you get a NameError for `new_string` first.

Comment: If you have a list of things, and want to join them with commas, why not `','.join(some_list)`?  In this case `some_list` could also be a generator expression if you need to modify each element in a list or other collection. This definitely smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually starting with. You would typically use some versions of `','.join()` to make a comma separated string, but it's hard to say with what you given us. I recommend editing the question to be in the form: 1. here's what I'm starting with, 2. here's what I want, 3. here's what I've tried.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to render a list as a string of comma separated values is `str.join`.  If your list items aren't strings, use `str()` on each individual item as you `join` them:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3]
>>> ",".join(str(n) for n in numbers)
'1,2,3'
```

Comment: That's a job for `map`. Or the whole thing maybe a job for `csv` (can't tell as long as they keep their stuff secret).

Answer (score -1):

if you want to remove the last char of a string in python you can do this:

`new_string = new_string[:-1]` or just `print(new_string[:-1])`

However I'd recommend you check to see if it's the last element and not add the comma that time:

```
new_string = ''
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if i + 1 == len(my_list):
        new_string += f'{item}'
    else:
        new_string += f'{item},'
```

Comment: Bad idea. Better don't add that comma in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
#your ,ed output
mystr = "1,2,3,4,"
#removes the last item of the string
mylist = list(mystr)
mystr = ""
mylist[len(mylist)-1] = "";
for x in mylist:
mystr += x

#prints output(1,2,3,4)
print(mystr)
```

the first part sets 'myvar' to "1,2,3,4,"

then it turns 'myvar' into a list and removes the last element

replace 'myvar' width your output